# Compilation error Unexpected token '<' my first app React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

It is my first app with react and it is part of an online course. Everything worked fine until I create a component in a separate file for it to receive props. I think it is important to comment that this file changes its name and location due to the instructor's specifications, but it still does not make calls, that is, I do not know if this affected it. Another thing is that when I modify the code and refresh the browser indicates the compilation error but it does not take into account the modification of the code and I must close the command line screen and restart the yarn so that it sees the applied changes.

```
export default class DishComents extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
      <div>
            <Card>
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>{this.props.name}</CardTitle>
                <CardText>{this.props.coments}</CardText>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </div> 


      );
    }
  }
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkPBj.png)

Comment: Definitely some file had been corrupted, the solution was to create a new App, configure it and recreate all the files from the old application. Everything works well

Answer (score 0):

can you check if the error is in this file?

This is what your file has to look like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class DishComents extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>{this.props.name}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>{this.props.coments}</CardText>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe the error is in another file, can you check it out?

EDIT: try to do it stateless because you dont have any state.

```
import React from "react";

export default function DishComents(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle>{props.name}</CardTitle>
          <CardText>{props.coments}</CardText>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, i import these     import  React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 
"reactstrap";           Unexpected token in <div>

Comment: As this component is stateless , try to write the component as follows:

    export default function DishComents(props) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Card>
            <CardBody>
              <CardTitle>{props.name}</CardTitle>
              <CardText>{props.coments}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    }

Comment: I've already tried it throws the same error. I have read with similar problems that in many cases it is a problem with babel, but the truth is that I did not understand much what they explained. Thanks for helping me.